# Trouble with generating _site files in Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I just migrated to another computer and installed Jekyll. Now I can't seems to get Jekyll to generate my website. When I run `jekyll --no-server` I get:

```
/Users/sb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
Configuration from /Users/sb/Sites/drb/_config.yml
Building site: /Users/sb/Sites/drb -> ./_site
/Users/sb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse': (<unknown>): did not find expected ',' or ']' while parsing a flow sequence at line 6 column 13 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /Users/sb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse_stream'
    from /Users/sb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:151:in `parse'
    from /Users/sb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:127:in `load'
    from /Users/sb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/convertible.rb:33:in `read_yaml'
    from /Users/sb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/post.rb:39:in `initialize'
    from /Users/sb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:163:in `new'
    from /Users/sb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:163:in `block in read_posts'
    from /Users/sb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:161:in `each'
    from /Users/sb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:161:in `read_posts'
    from /Users/sb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:128:in `read_directories'
    from /Users/sb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:98:in `read'
    from /Users/sb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:38:in `process'
    from /Users/sb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/bin/jekyll:250:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/jekyll:19:in `load'
    from /Users/sb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/jekyll:19:in `<main>'
    from /Users/sb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /Users/sb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Jekyll seems to be working correctly, but my markdown files in `_posts` do not seem to be converted to HTML, since I do not have any files in `_site`. Deleting the `_site` directory then regenerating my site creates a new `_site`, but there is no content inside the folder. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: What version of Ruby were you running before? Can you think of any dependency issues that could arise from the computer switch?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was running ruby 1.9.2 on my previous machine, but I can not think of any dependency issues.

Comment: Per your recommendation, I also installed 1.9.2, which was the version of Ruby I previously used—I still am having the same problem with 1.9.2.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Turned out to be the use of a question mark in the YAML front matter.

Comment: `layout: nil` turned out to be o problem. Interesting. The same code works on my other computer.

Comment: I believe you can use question marks in your YAML front matter if you enclose the string in quotes.